# Joining same table twice in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I'm building an application on Laravel where I need to join the same table with some condition

I'm having a `project_associate_brand` table which includes following columns:

```
project_id   |   brand_id   |   product_group_id    |   product_sub_group_id
```

I need to fetch out `brands` associated with project with respect to `product_group_id` and `product_sub_group_id` and also which are the other `brands` associated with them

To execute this I tried:

```
AssociatedBrands::where('project_associate_brand.brand_id', '=', $id)
    ->leftjoin('project_associate_brand as pr_brand', function ($join) {
        $join->on('project_associate_brand.project_id', '=', 'pr_brand.project_id')
            ->where('project_associate_brand.product_group_id', '=', 'pr_brand.product_group_id')
            ->where('project_associate_brand.product_subgroup_id', '=', 'pr_brand.product_subgroup_id');
    })
    ->leftjoin('brands as b', function ($join) {
        $join->on('pr_brand.brand_id', '=', 'b.id')->whereNotIn('pr_brand.brand_id', [$id]);
    })
    ->select('project_associate_brand.*', 'b.id as other_brand_id', 'b.title as other_brand_title')
->paginate(15);
```

I'm not getting the desired results, I tried removing few of the where clause, when I remove `product_group_id` and `product_sub_group_id` contraints I was able to get results

```
AssociatedBrands::where('project_associate_brand.brand_id', '=', $id)
    ->leftjoin('project_associate_brand as pr_brand', function ($join) {
        $join->on('project_associate_brand.project_id', '=', 'pr_brand.project_id');
        
            //Removed other where clause
            
    })
    ->leftjoin('brands as b', function ($join) {
        $join->on('pr_brand.brand_id', '=', 'b.id')->whereNotIn('pr_brand.brand_id', [$id]);
    })
    ->select('project_associate_brand.*', 'b.id as other_brand_id', 'b.title as other_brand_title')
->paginate(15);
```

Any better approach is welcome. Further I would like to execute `with()` eager loading of relations

Comment: Why don't you just declare correct relations at your AssociatedBrands model? So that instead of making customised queries you can just take what you need with $model->relationName...

Comment: Please try to show an expected table rows and query results (2-3 just for example) as you currently do really strange query build and it's not clear what you want to achive..